# How can I query the Full Name field in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

In Windows Server 2003 Active Directory there was no UI to access the FullName field - see [this blog post](http://blog.techgalaxy.net/archives/2901) for a discussion of this, and how Display Name is *not* the same as Full Name.

In Windows Server 2008 Active Directory, the Full Name field can be seen on the General Properties section of the User windows in ADUC.

The Full Name field is used in the Global Address List.  I have found that in some cases the Full Name field has been populated with the username, rather than the full name, meaning that users can't find these colleagues in the GAL as they are out of order.

I want to extract the username and FullName fields from AD so that I can find all the accounts where the two fields are the same (I'm not trying to do this comparison with an LDAP query - I can do it in Excel once I extracted all the values).

However, I can't find anywhere how I would actually refer to the field labelled "Full Name".  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

Based on some tinkering it looks like the two attributes that would be important to you that change when you rename a user object are: the "cn" attribute and the "name" attribute. Both of these attributes reflect the value entered in the Full Name field when renaming a user. You could extract either of those to accomplish your goal, I suppose.